# Text in two columns at appropriate levels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the text in right column and a question (`ВОПРОС 1`), (`ВОПРОС 2`), etc. that is relevant to some specific paragraph in the left column so that the question is displayed at the same level as the text (so directly next to it, and not near some other paragraph). How can I implement such a feature?

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.right {
  width: 75%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
  <h2>А. Ф. Керенский. Гатчина</h2>
  Издалека́. Сборник статей 1920 – 1921 гг. Париж: 1922
  <br></br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column left">
      <br></br>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">(ВОПРОС 1)
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">1. Что Керенский имеет в виду, говоря, что ВП боролось с большевиками?</span>
      </div>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction3()">(ВОПРОС 2)
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup3">2. В чём Керенский обвиняет соц. партии?</span>
      </div>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction4()">(ВОПРОС 3)
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup4">3. Как ВП готовилось к подавлению большевистского мятежа? </span>
      </div>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction5()">(ВОПРОС 4)
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup5">4.  Какую позицию занял ближайшие помощник Керенского, командующий Петербургского округа полковник Полковников?</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column right">
      <p style="text-align:justify">
        Последний акт борьбы Революционного Временного правительства с большевиками с п р а в а и с л е в а продолжался с 24 октября по 1 ноября 1917 г. Да, я особенно настаиваю на том, что мы боролись сразу на два фронта. И никто никогда не будет в состоянии
        опровергнуть ту несомненную связь, которая существовала между большевистским восстанием и усилиями реакции свергнуть Временное правительство и повернуть государственный корабль вспять к берегу социальной реакции.
        <br></br>
        После безуспешной для заговорщиков и столь несчастной для государства попытки свергнуть Временное правительство вооруженной рукой ген. Корнилова общественные группы, поддержавшие «диктатора» и связанные с ним, постановили не оказывать правительству в
        случае столкновения его с большевиками никакой помощи. Их стратегический план состоял в том, чтобы сначала не препятствовать успеху вооруженного восстания большевиков, а затем, после падения ненавистного Временного правительства, быстро подавить
        большевистский «бунт». Таким образом должны были быть достигнуты, наконец, цели, поставленные Корниловскому восстанию.
      </p>
      <p style="text-align:justify">
        Военные и штатские стратеги, авторы этого замечательного плана, были твердо убеждены в том, что большевистский триумф не представит из себя никакой серьезной опасности и что через 3 - 4 недели «здоровые элементы» русского народа справятся с бунтующей
        массой и установят в России «сильную власть». Увы, выполнив блестяще первую, так сказать, пассивную часть своего плана - «свергнув» руками большевиков Временное правительство, наши «патриоты» оказались совершенно не способными победить большевиков
        не только в три месяца,
        <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction2()">но и в три года!..<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Керенский имеет виду Гражданскую войну, которая уже продолжалась три года на момент написания этой статьи в 1920 г. </span>
        </div>
        <br></br>
      </p>
      <p style="text-align:justify">
        Около 20 октября начали большевики осуществлять в Петербурге свой план вооруженного восстания для свержения Временного правительства во имя «мира, хлеба и скорейшего созыва Учредительного собрания». Эта подготовка шла довольно успешно, в частности и потому,
        что остальные социалистические партии и советские группировки, относясь ко всем сведениям о готовящихся событиях как к «контрреволюционным измышлениям», даже не пытались своевременно мобилизовать свои силы, способные в нужный момент оказать сопротивление
        большевистским затеям, так сказать, внутри самой «революционной демократии». Со своей стороны, правительство готовилось к подавлению мятежа, но, не рассчитывая на окончательно деморализованный корниловской авантюрой гарнизон Петербурга, изыскивало
        другие средства воздействия. По моему приказу с фронта должны были в срочном порядке выслать в Петербург войска и первые эшелоны с Северного фронта должны были появиться в столице 24 октября.
        <br></br>
      </p>
      <p style="text-align:justify">
        В то же время
        <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction6()"> полк. Полковников <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup6"> Гео́ргий Петро́вич Полко́вников (1883-1918) — российский военный деятель, главнокомандующий Петроградским военным округом в сентябре — октябре 1917 года, последнее воинское звание — полковник. </span>
        </div>, командующий войсками Петербургского военного округа, получил приказ разработать подробный план подавления мятежа. Ему же было предложено своевременно взять на учет, организовать все верные долгу части того же гарнизона. Полк. Полковников
        каждое утро лично представлял мне ра́порт, причем постоянно докладывал, что во вверенных ему войсках, которыми может располагать правительство, «вполне достаточно» сил для того, чтобы справиться с готовящимся восстанием. К великому сожалению,
        мы, члены правительства, слишком поздно узнали, что как сам Полковников, так и часть его штаба вели в эти роковые дни д в о й н у ю и г р у и примыкали как раз к той части офицерства, в планы которой входило свержение Временного правительства
        руками большевиков.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide any screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tags `<a></a>` in your  `<div class="popup">`, that will use id of paragraph and will move this paragraph onclicked your answer.

```
     <a href="#click"><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">(ВОПРОС 1)
            <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">1. Что Керенский имеет в виду, говоря, что ВП боролось с большевиками?</span>
          </div></a>
     <p id="click">
     your paragraph
     </p>
```

And I recommend you one idea:

If you want that the user pays attention оn paragraph, you can change background color of this paragraph by clicking on it.

```
<script>
function changeColor(id)
{
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // backcolor
}
</script>

<div id="myid">Hello There !!</div>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor('myid'); return false;">Change Color</a>
```